# How to use Camel Exchange Header in Camel Component propertites?

Tags: apache-camel

I am using a CXF component which will take username and password as its properties and I am getting username and password in Camel Exchange Header, So I tried to set this way:

```
<to uri="cxf:{myurl}?dataFormat=MESSAGE&amp;username=${in.header.username}&amp;password=${in.header.password}"/>
```

But it is giving me authentication failure error as username and password are not set properly.

Comment: please style your code using `ctrl+k` or with 4spaces for each line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this FAQ about how to use dynamic values in the to

- http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

So by using recipient list EIP you can do this

```
<recipientList>
  <simple>cxf:{myurl}?dataFormat=MESSAGE&username=${in.header.username}&password=${in.header.password}"</simple>
</recipientList>
```